# unable to form structure and update the values other than currentTab via iterating the items data

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to form the structure like expectedOutput by iterating items data and updating the value only
if matches mnemonic other than currentTab which is present in items data

```js
let items = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim'}]},
             {tab: 'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'kim'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim'}]},
             {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'wint'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'telt'}]}]

let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = {mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'}

let expectedOutput = [{tab:'tab1',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'alm'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'jim'}]},
         {tab: 'tab2',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'tim'}]},
         {tab:'tab3',info:[{mnemonic:'first',value:'newValue'},{mnemonic:'second',value:'telt'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a loop over the items and check in each info array. If menomic matches than update the same.

```js
let items = [{
    tab: 'tab1',
    info: [{
      mnemonic: 'first',
      value: 'alm'
    }, {
      mnemonic: 'second',
      value: 'jim'
    }]
  },
  {
    tab: 'tab2',
    info: [{
      mnemonic: 'first',
      value: 'kim'
    }, {
      mnemonic: 'second',
      value: 'tim'
    }]
  },
  {
    tab: 'tab3',
    info: [{
      mnemonic: 'first',
      value: 'wint'
    }, {
      mnemonic: 'second',
      value: 'telt'
    }]
  }
]

let currentTab = 'tab1';
let obj = {
  mnemonic: 'first',
  value: 'newValue'
}
const res = items.map(item => {
  let info = []
  if (item.tab != currentTab) {
    item.info.forEach(it => {
      const temp = { ...it
      }
      if (temp.mnemonic === obj.mnemonic) {
        temp.value = obj.value
      }
      info.push(temp)
    })
  }
  const t = info.length ? [...info] : [...item.info]
  return {
    tab: item.tab,
    info: [...t]
  }
})

console.log(res);
console.log(items)
```

Comment: is conditional check necessary, can you explain const t = info.length ? [...info] : [...item.info]

Comment: if we have a copy of the data then take that one else take the original one.

Comment: in order to retain the other values, this check is necessary